# Can we use @Autowired annotation as a constructor argument?

Tags: java, spring, constructor, nullpointerexception, autowired

In my case I am trying to use `Environment` class to read properties. I tried two options.

**Option 1 -  I tried to use `@Autowired` the `Enviornment` class as shown in the following example.**

```
@Service("idmHelper")
public class IdmHelper {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public IdmHelper() {
       env.getProperty('property-name')
       ...
   }
}
```

Here it gives a `NullPointerException`. Becuase `env` is null.

**Option 2 -  I tried to use `@Autowired` inside the constructor as an argument, as shown in the following example.**

```
@Service("idmHelper")
public class IdmHelper {

    public IdmHelper(@Autowired Environment env) {
       env.getProperty('property-name')
       ...
   }
}
```

Here the `env` will get an object and I can access the properties. But I am getting the following error;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGE7.png)

I am new to spring-boot, can someone explain why I am getting this error. I doubt that it is something to do with initiating the constructor. Please correct me If I am wrong.

This is my full code;
[Full-code-of-idm-helper-class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTS4.png)

Comment: How does line 81 exactly look like in your option 2?

Comment: You don't even need the `@Autowired` annotation on the parameter of the constructor (unless you're using an old version of Spring). But you do need to have `Environment` configured as a Spring bean.

Comment: @dunni The line is  - `public IdmHelper(@Autowired Environment env) {`

Comment: Doubtful that this line causes a NPE. Can you show your real code?

Comment: @HashanMaduwantha i doubt that. The line that throws the NPE is `env.getProperty`.

Comment: @dunni I have added the full code with a debug poing at the end please have a look.

Comment: @f1sh I have added a debug point, you can see env.getproperty works fine.

Comment: And which line now causes the exception? Your code doesn't fit to the exception that you posted.

Comment: @dunni yeah I did some changes and That's why it is changed. I ll run again and let you know the exact line.

Comment: Your screenshot shows there's wayyy much more going on than what you posted. The autowiring works. You just have a regular NullPointerException somewhere. Why didn't you include your code from the start? You have people guessing for 45 minutes here.

Comment: @f1sh I was trying to be more specific because of you peoples' ease, also the code is very large, that is why i pointed out the location where error occurs. let me reformat the issue.

Comment: @dunni I ve updated the issue, please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@Service("idmHelper")
public class IdmHelper {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    private var prop = null ; 

    @PostConstruct
    public init() {
       prop = env.getProperty('property-name');
   }
}
```

Other solution :

```
@Service("idmHelper")
public class IdmHelper {

    @Autowired 
    public IdmHelper(Environment env) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This one works fine for me. @Zorglube

Comment: If that's work from you fine. However it's definitly possible to put some `autowiering` on a constructor, you ca,n write it like that : `
@Service("idmHelper")
public class IdmHelper {

    @Autowired 
    public IdmHelper(Environment env) {
       ...
   }
}`